How to convert the linear polynomial matrix problem to the high dimensional semidefinite programming
Given a set of polynomial function $f_1(x)$, $f_2(y)$, $f_3(z)$, and a $f_0$ and a linear functional $\alpha$ constructed from $\partial_t$ and to ask if
$$\alpha(f_0+\sum_i f_i)=0$$
for all $x,y,z>0$ was possible, where $x(t),y(t),z(t)$ implicitly dependent on $t$. This can be done by attempt to maximize $\alpha f_0$. The component of $\alpha$ are linear and can be vectorized.
This was similar to the SDPB(semi definite programming bootstrap), the maximize  $$b\cdot y $$ and the polynomial matrix input  $$M_j^0 (x) +\sum_{n=1}^N y_n M_j^n(x) \succeq 0 $$
The basis of the vectorized component of $\alpha$, $\alpha_n$, acted on the functions, and $\alpha$ itself was represented by the coefficients $y_n$. The corresponding $f_j$ that was acted upon became the polynomial matrices $M_j^n$.
In a particular set up, one would like to see if it's possible that $\alpha(\sum_j f_j)>0$ for all $x,y,z$. This could be achieved by requiring that
$$\alpha f_j >0$$ for each $j$ while maximize $\alpha f_0$.
Thus, it became the requirement that, three vector labeled by $j$,
$$\sum_n y_n (\alpha_n f_j)>0$$
for all $x,y,z$ and for all $j$.
It bothered me a bit, because the SDPB was used to solve the PMP(polynomial matrix problem), such that, its condition was $\sum_{n=1}^N y_n M_j^n(x) \succeq 0 $ positive semidefinite matrices. But $\sum_n y_n (\alpha_n f_j)>0$ was effectively stating that the sum of a group of $1\times 1$ matrices were positive.
It would be reasonable to assume that there might exist an alternative translation from the PMP to SDPB, such that it actually required a
$$\sum_{n=1}^N y_n M_J^n(x) \succeq 0 $$ where $M_J^n$ might be a $2\times 2$ matrices of $3\times 3$ matrices such that
$$M_J^n(x)=\begin{pmatrix}
G_{1,1}(f_1,f_2,f_3,\alpha_n)& G_{1,2}(f_1,f_2,f_3,\alpha_n)\\
G_{2,1}(f_1,f_2,f_3,\alpha_n)& G_{2,2}(f_1,f_2,f_3,\alpha_n)
\end{pmatrix}$$
to be positive semi definite.
Is there an alternative to reformulate the above PMP to the SDPB utilize the "positive semi definite matrices"?
